# Want to modify props but i cant find them

Tags: reactjs, frontend, grafana

I'm making some modifications on this app by only understanding the syntax, i don't understand very much how it is built.
If someone could help me understand how the props get passed to this component that would be nice (i want to modify the props) [React file](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/public/app/core/components/sidemenu/SideMenuDropDown.tsx) .

Answer (score 0):

The props are being passed at line 26

```
{childrenLinks.map((child, index) => {
    return <DropDownChild child={child} key={`${child.url}-${index}`} />;
})}
```

childrenLink is also coming from a prop called linked passed from the parent component that calls SideMenuDropDown component.

Comment: That's my main problem i want to find the parent component that calls SideMenuDropDown

Comment: It is being imported in a different file

Answer (score 0):

I actually found it, it gets populated from the backend there is a file index.go in /pkg/api that does it